# Pycharm - How do I set the page margin?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I've recently come across an issue when using Pycharm where the margin of the page on any new project I open will centre the margin. I want my code positioned to the left which I think is the default setting - I'm not sure what has caused this to change. I have googled around for a solution but still not able to get to the solution.

Please see my image attached below in the link for details. Any help is much appreciated.

kind regards.

[Screenshot-of-pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUZBb.png)

Comment: Have you checked the section 'Reformat line indents' on https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#tabs_and_indents? Does it solve the problem?

Comment: i tried this though I believe this is a setting for changing the tabs indents but doesnt specify how you want the margin on the page i.e. left, centre, right. 
I would think something like this is straightforward by not in Pycharm !